# How to create a batch file that output file name in txt?

Tags: windows-7, batch-file

I want to copy the list of all file name into a txt with a bat. For example, if I have a .bat and if I move that bat to D:/123 or anywhere and click on it, I will get a text file with all file name of 123 in it in 123 folder.
How can I do it?
ty!

Comment: Does it have to be .bat? And whats wrong with `dir >> listOfFile.txt `

Comment: yes, I dont want to use cmd. is it possble?

Comment: I mean in your batch file. All a batch file is, is a series of commands that you would use in cmd.exe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you double click on a batch file from Windows Explorer, the default directory is set to the location of the batch file. So the following simple script should work as long as it is called by double clicking on it.

```
@dir /b /a-d >files.txt
```

If you want the script to work regardless of how it was called, then

```
@dir /b /a-d "%~dp0" >"%~dp0files.txt"
```

Note that `%~dp0` evaluates to the path of the currently executing script, including a trailing `\`.

Comment: @user300418 - I simplified the first code a bit.

Answer (score 0):

The dir command lists files in a directory. Append flags to get the output in the format you want, then redirect the output to a file with the >-symbol, e.g.: `dir > list.txt`.